# Show that $X^2 + Y^2$ and $\frac{X}{\sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}}$ are independent

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent standard normal random variables. Show that $X^2 + Y^2$ and $\frac{X}{\sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}}$ are independent.

My thoughts: we can set $U= X^2 + Y^2$ and $V=\frac{X^2}{X^2 + Y^2}$; however, then I have trouble calculating the Jacobi since $X=\pm \sqrt{UV}$ and $Y= \pm \sqrt{U-UV}$.

Comment: Just write down the probability density, then express it in terms of U, V.

Comment: What is the purpose of introducing $Z$? :D

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Sorry, the second part of the problem (including $Z$) requires the independence in the first part.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2016419/321264,https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2017359/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know $R=X^2\sim\chi^2(1)$ and $S=Y^2\sim\chi^2(1)$ right, then, instead of using definition of $U$ and $V$ in terms of $X$ and $Y$, try to use the definition of them in temrs of $R$ and $S$, so you will find easier jacobian

as additional notes, $V$ is beta distributed