# Finding PDF of $Z \thicksim Q / \sqrt{Q^2 + R^2}$ where $Q, R \thicksim N(0,1)$?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have only done simple convolutions up to this point to find joint PDFs and am lost about how to proceed with finding the PDF of $Z \thicksim \frac{Q}{\sqrt{Q^2 + R^2}}$ where $Q, R \thicksim N(0,1)$. How do I approach finding the PDF of $Z$?

Comment: FYI, the exercise is based on the well known fact that, if $Q$ and $R$ are independent and standard normal, then $(Q,R)=(Y\cos\Theta,Y\sin\Theta)$ where $(Y,\Theta)$ is independent with known distributions. In particular, $\Theta$ is uniform on $\mathbb R/2\pi\mathbb Z$, and you are asking for the distribution of $Z=\cos\Theta$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that $Q$ and $R$ are independent. First, $F_Z(z)=0$ for $z\le -1$ and $F_Z(z)=1$ for $z\ge 1$. Also
$$
\mathsf{P}(Z\le z\)=\mathsf{E}\!\left[\mathsf{P}\!\left(Q\le z\sqrt{Q^2+R^2}\mid R\right)\right].
$$
For $z\in (-1,1)$,
$$
\mathsf{P}\!\left(Q\le z\sqrt{Q^2+r^2}\right)=\mathsf{P}\!\left(Q\le z\sqrt{\frac{r^2}{1-z^2}}\right)=\Phi\!\left(z\sqrt{\frac{r^2}{1-z^2}}\right)
$$

so that

$$
F_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Phi\left(z\sqrt{\frac{r^2}{1-z^2}}\right)\phi(r)dr=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\arcsin(z)}{\pi}, \quad z\in (-1,1).
$$

and the corresponding pdf is $f_Z(z)=\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-z^2}}$ on $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Missing closing brace, but (+1).

Comment: @d.k.o. Could you explain what the phi symbol represents, and how you were able to use an expectation in the first equality?

Comment: @potpie $\Phi$ and $\phi$ are the CDF and the PDF of the standard normal r.v. and the first equality follows from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation

Answer (score 1):

**Comment.** Demonstration by simulation in R statistical software.
Generated a million realizations of your ratio, which I called $X$. 
A histogram of these shows the simulated distribution. Plotted
@d.k.o.'s density through the histogram. Fits nicely.

```
 m = 10^6; q = rnorm(m); r = rnorm(m)
 x = q/sqrt(q^2 + r^2)
 hist(x, prob=T, col="wheat")
 curve((pi*sqrt(1-x^2))^-1, lwd=2, col="blue",add=T)
```

[image]

*Note:* This is a 4-parameter Beta distribution on $(-1,1).$
See Wikipedia for details, if interested.