# Independence of functions of normal random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, independence

Let $X, Y$ be independent standard normal random variables. Show that 
$$U=X^2+Y^2 \hbox{ and }  V=\frac{X}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}$$ are independent.

The transformation is $T(x,y)=(u,v)$ where $T: (-\infty,\infty)\times (-\infty,\infty)\to [0,\infty)\times [-1,1]$.

Note that $T$ is not 1-1 because of $T(x,y)=T(x,-y)$.

But $T$ is 1-1 on $(-\infty,\infty)\times (0,\infty)$ and on $(-\infty,\infty)\times (-\infty,0)$.

We consider $$T^{-1}_1(u,v)=(\sqrt{u}v, \sqrt{u(1-v^2)})$$ and 
$$T^{-1}_2(u,v)=(\sqrt{u}v, -\sqrt{u(1-v^2)})$$.

The joint density of $X, Y$ is given by $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}$.

By the transformation formula, the joint density $g(u,v)$ of $U, V$ is given by
$$g(u,v)=f(\sqrt{u}v, \sqrt{u(1-v^2)})|J_1|+f(\sqrt{u}v, -\sqrt{u(1-v^2)})|J_2|$$ 
where $J_i$ is the Jacobian of $T^{-1}_i$ $i=1, 2$. Note that for $i=1, 2$

$$|J_i|=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-v^2}}.$$

Therefore, $g(u,v)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-u/2}\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-v^2}}$ with $0\leq u<+\infty, -1<v<1$, and hence $U$ and $V$ are independent.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: transformation theorem but the map is not invertible.

Comment: How about a brute force approach: show that $\mathbb{P}[V \in A|U=u] = \mathbb{P}[V \in A]$

Comment: Hint: polar coordinates.

Comment: The phrase "polar coordinates" could be taken to be about $99\%$ of a complete answer provided the person posing the question is somewhat competent in the use of polar coordinates. How big a proviso that is, is a live question. $\qquad$

Comment: See the comments for [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016419/finding-pdf-of-z-thicksim-q-sqrtq2-r2-where-q-r-thicksim-n0-1/).

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2017359/321264.

Comment: OK, thanks. Anyway, this is a different solution so it can be kept here.