# Find the distribution of $\frac{X}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}$ where $X$ and $Y$ independent $N(0,1)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

Given that $X$ and $Y$ independent $N(0,1)$, find the distribution of $\frac{X}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}$

I can find distribution of $\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ which is $f_Z(z)=ze^{-z^2/2}$, given that $Z=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$. I am having difficulty in find distribution of $\frac{X}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}$. Any guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider a polar transformation.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2016419/321264

Answer (score 0):

Hint $$Z=\frac{X}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+W^2}}$$

where $W=Y/X$ are idd standard gaussian. But then $W$ is [Cauchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Related_distributions).